# How can I make Debian restart to GRUB?

Tags: debian, gnome, shutdown, reboot

I just installed Debian and wanted to change it so when I hit Restart on the Shut Down dialog in GNOME that it restarts the computer, instead of just restarting the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to make sure APM is enabled in the kernel and install gnome-power-manager:
http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=43078&start=0